# Unable to shink C: Partion

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, gparted

I have been trying to shrink my C: drive partion but currently to no avail. I am unsure about using 3rd party software to do it (such as [gParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or [EaseUS Partition Master Free](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)). So I have a 1TB harddrive with 4 partions. Running Windows 8.1.

My main goal is to get a 40GB partion for a dual boot of Linux. So I first tried to shrink the C: but the max I could shrink it by was only 9000MB so I followed the instructions at [this link](http://mindwithheart.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/windows-8-fix-you-cannot-shrink-a-volume-beyond-the-point-where-any-unmovable-files-are-located/) (disabling paging, defrag and disabling hibernation) . This enabled me to shrink it by a maximum of 400000MB(ish). I went ahead and tried to shrink the partion by 40000MB but it came up with the error saying there is not enough space.

Below is a screenshot of the current partions:

[image]

Comment: EaseUS Partition could do it clearly why you don't use it?

Comment: Not sure about the legitimacy and saw problems about not being able boot after shrink/move partion

Comment: The standard Windows defrag reduces the number of file fragments, but it often reduces the amount of contiguous free space. Other defraggers make a better job of optimising free space. Have a look at (http://www.UBCD4Win.com/) and (http://www.Hiren.Info/pages/bootcd), both freeware. I have used the former extensively, while I have used the latter less, but it is more up-to-date - several of the utilities appear on both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](http://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files), [Cannot shrink C: Partition beyond 297 MB](http://superuser.com/questions/744770/cannot-shrink-c-partition-beyond-297-mb)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to defrag the drive first? I am not sure, but I believe this could be some kind of prevention from cutting off some file fragments.

Comment: Yes I have already defraged, cant get below 2% fragmented

Comment: 2% should by OK. Now I see I misread your post! If you are trying to shrink the system drive from within the system itself, you can't be able to do it. You will almost certainly have to use some 3rd party OFFLINE software. By offline I mean your Windows installation must NOT be booted at the time you are modifying its partitions. I recommend gParted live (http://gparted.org/livecd.php) I have a lot of experience using it and it never let me down. It's pretty easy to use, fully GUI supported and fast as well. :)